# API and the host URL in Angular

Tags: angular, api, rest

I have a problem to understand the binding to an API from an Angular application. Currently I'm developing a small GUI which should run on an embedded system served with Nginx. The backend is written with Python Flask. So much to say...

In this early development state the URL's are clear and the communication is working. The Angular serve command runs on known http://localhost:4200/ and the Flask backend on http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/. Great. I put the API URL in a constant in environment. It is something like:

```
...
/* GET a list of serial ports from the backend server. */
  getSerialPorts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/' + 'serialports')
      .pipe( retry(1), map(data => {
        console.log(data)
...

/* Or */
  getSerialPorts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(backend_url + 'serialports')
      .pipe( retry(1), map(data => {
        console.log(data)
```

Now my problem is in a production/stable environment: My embedded device have a IPV4 address within the URL. But the address can be changed. Now I don't know if I really have a problem, but I'm missing the understanding of it - and that I like to have first.

Nginx is presenting the Angular GUI at http://a.b.c.d/
The backend lives on the same host in http://a.b.c.d/api/

How can I go on with storing the host name?
Do I need to store the host name for addressing the API?
Can I link to /api/... and Angular do the rest for me?

(Sorry for the novice question - but I like to understand what is going on and how I can handle that.)

Comment: Actually I'm doing something of: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-hostname](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-hostname) So I'm getting the host name on the machine which are calling the Angular GUI. This is the source of my api location. 
But I hope there is a better way of doing this...?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the host name of the API as a apiBaseUrl variable. You never know if you'll need to move the backend to a different host. Right now they are both on the same domain but in some cases this is not the case.

Comment: Which host name should I store? On the embedded system you call "http://a.b.c.d/" and you are getting the Angular GUI from Nginx. Now the Angular GUI is working on the client and not on the server. It need's to know from which server it was served than it can call back to the servers API.

Comment: Can you provide some code? When you say it is working on the client and not on the server, what do you mean?